# echo <option> compiles wrong, and $_POST[''] doesn't return selected value

Tags: php

I populate my `select` from an array, in the loop I `echo` lines like this

```
echo "<option value='".$company->id."' selected>".$company->name."</option>";
```

when this compiles it compiles like this:

`<option selected="" value="1">Company</option>`

Also when I try to retrieve the value of `<select name='companies'>`
with line like this `$_POST['companies']` I get nothing back.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your form method is `POST` because default form method is `GET`.

Comment: Sorry everyone I made such a stupid mistake, my Select was outside the form. Working tired is not a good idea... I had select just above the form and I didn't notice.. Everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

If your form method is post then you will get value with `$_POST['companies']`

If you are using `selected` for each option then please remove that because in that you will get value of always last option